# How to get name of config object?

Tags: java, typesafe, typesafe-config

I want to get name of config object. Example

```
Config conf = ConfigFactory.load("file").getConfig("myexample");
```

And how to

```
String name = conf.getCurrentName(); // there is no like getCurrentName method
```

So `name` should be equal `myexample`.

Comment: Did you start coding for your problem ?

Comment: Before you start comment, it would be better to read the entire question and to look at tags.